# Why I get this error on laravel project and npm run watch?

Tags: laravel, npm

today I started a new project on Laravel 5.7, but I have a problem when I try to `npm run dev` or `run watch`.

I did:

```
laravel new something
cd something
composer install
cp .env.example .env
php artisan key:generate
php artisan serve
```

perfect :D

but...

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

**error!**

```
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"

/Users/car/Sites/something/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:231
                throw err;
                ^
```

If I try with run watch, same thing.

I tried:

- rm -r nodes_modules
- rm package-lock.json
- npm install

same thing

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
npm uninstall ajv
npm install ajv@6.8.1
```

To install an older version of ajv.

Ref: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8768